# Control custom panes for Leaflet Geojson SVG icons

Tags: leaflet, svg, rendering, z-index

In Leaflet v1.03 I have *n* layers of SVG icons which should be rendered on custom panes. I try to use the panes to control the zindex of items.

Within the L.geoJson options I set the pane as well as the SVG renderer with a pane option itself. Neither works. The SVG render order seems to be random.

Is the renderer option actually supported in Leaflet v1.03? The option itself is not listed in the current documentation.

Would I need to create a layer group in order to control the panes of SVG icons created with the pointToLayer method?

```
map.createPane('400');
map.getPane('400').style.zIndex = 400;
map.getPane('400').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

new L.geoJson(dots400, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'blue_dot.svg',
                iconSize: [10, 10]
            }),
            interactive: false
        });
    },
    renderer: L.svg({pane: '400'}),
    pane: {pane: '400'},
    onEachFeature: null
}).addTo(map);

map.createPane('500');
map.getPane('500').style.zIndex = 500;
map.getPane('500').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

new L.geoJson(dots500, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'red_dot.svg',
                iconSize: [10, 10]
            }),
            interactive: false
        });
    },
    renderer: L.svg({pane: '500'}),
    pane: {pane: '500'},
    onEachFeature: null
}).addTo(map);
```

Here is a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/abrurqwn/

I want the red dot to be drawn on top.

Comment: Could you create a js.fiddle example?

Comment: Sure... https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/abrurqwn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify the [pane](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layer-pane) as an option of your markers (i.e. any individual layer).

```js
L.geoJSON(dots400, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      pane: '400', // pane option is for individual layers.
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'blue_dot.svg',
        iconSize: [10, 10]
      }),
      interactive: false
    });
  },
  //renderer: L.svg({pane: '400'}),
  //pane: {pane: '400'},
  onEachFeature: null
}).addTo(map);
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abrurqwn/5/

`pane` option on groups (like your GeoJSON layer group) do not have any effect as of today, see [Leaflet issue #4279](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4279)

Furthermore, you just need to pass the pane *name*, as you have done for your label layers in your JSFiddle.